# accessing product sub categories like ebay in django form

Tags: django, forms

i am trying to replicate the category structure sites like Ebay use when posting a product. For example, if you want to post an Iphone for sale, you go to post an ad, choose a category from the drop down menu on the form('electronics & computers'), then choose a subcategory of "phones", then the last sub category of "iphone". To create this structure i am using django-categories. Creating a product in the admin page works file, the admin form allows me to choose from a drop down menu of every category, however i can't seem to replicate that same process on my own form, to give users the ability to choose from the many categories.

If your not aware if django-categories it is a Modified Preorder Tree Traversal.

Here is my advert model

```
class Advert(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', blank=True, null=True)  
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=COND_CATEGORIES, blank=False, null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=14, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Here is the category model

```
class Category(CategoryBase):


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
```

And here i the form that allows users to post an advert

```
class PostAdvertForm(forms.ModelForm):

    title = forms.CharField(label='Ad Title', required=True)
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Advert.category, label='Choose a category', required=True)
    price = forms.DecimalField(label='Price', required=True, widget=forms.TextInput())                                  
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':
                                          ('Please provide a detailed description'),
                                          'autofocus': 'autofocus'}), label='Description', required=True)
    condition = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Advert.COND_CATEGORIES, label='Condition', required=True)
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(label='Quantity', required=True, widget=forms.TextInput())
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Upload an image', required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Advert
        fields = (
            'title', 'category', 'quantity', 'condition', 'price', 'description', 
            'image')
```

Using advert.category on the choice field is not working due to "ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object is not iterable".

My question is how can i get the category list to appear on the choicefield?

EDIT:
Was just wondering, would this be possible to implement entirely with jquery on the front end and just send through the choosen category through the cleaned data? This way i would not even need to bother using django-categories on the backend, i could just store a massive load of categories.

2nd EDIT:

Looks like i got the first part of this to work, i have pasted the new form code below:

```
at = Advert.category.get_queryset()


class PostAdvertForm(forms.ModelForm):

    title = forms.CharField(label='Ad Title', required=True)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=cat, label='Choose a category', required=True)
    price = forms.DecimalField(label='Price', required=True, widget=forms.TextInput())                                  
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':
                                          ('Please provide a detailed description'),
                                          'autofocus': 'autofocus'}), label='Description', required=True)
    condition = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Advert.COND_CATEGORIES, label='Condition', required=True)
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(label='Quantity', required=True, widget=forms.TextInput())
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Upload an image', required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Advert
        fields = (
            'title', 'category', 'quantity', 'condition', 'price', 'description', 
            'image')
```

I have never used jquery before, is that the best option to create a flowing drop down style menu? I must make it so they can't choose a parent category, only the bottom child category.

Comment: You can give the choices in `def __init__` of `PostAdvertForm`. Take a look at https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/master/speedy/match/accounts/forms.py#L166-L177 and https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/master/speedy/core/base/utils.py#L116-L121

Answer (score 0):

Define a function `update_form_field_choices` (for example in `utils.py`):

```
def update_form_field_choices(field, choices):
    """
    Update both field.choices and field.widget.choices to the same value (list of choices).
    """
    field.choices = choices
    field.widget.choices = choices
```

Then, define method `__init__` in `PostAdvertForm`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And in this function, call this function, and replace `your_choices()` with a function that returns the correct choices. Remember the choices format (a tuple of tuples).

```
    update_form_field_choices(field=self.fields['category'], choices=your_choices())
```

Also remember, `ModelForm` defines the form fields for you, so you don't have to define them explicitly, unless you want to change something in the default definition.